# How to set sonar.junit.reportsPath property value from jenkins environment variable in Sonar Jenkins Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, sonar-runner

I have added SonarQube Scanner in the jenkins build job with the following analysis parameters as below...

```
sonar.projectKey=ProjectKey
sonar.projectBaseDir=/home/siva/xx/src/com/ond/XX/code/network/service
sonar.working.directory=/home/siva/XXX
sonar.junit.reportsPath=${folderpath}
```

And
Path to project properties : `/home/siva/.../service/sonar-project.properties`

Here the environment variable `folderpath` has proper value expected before sonarqube scanner build step and it is set under "Inject environment variables to the build process"

```
folderpath=/x/xx/xxx
```

But i see in the Analysis log the value for sonar.junit.reportsPath is not getting expended/set to proper value and is always taking unexpanded as `${folderpath}`

Any help on this appreciated.